# How to write a query with two ? placeholders in sequence?

Tags: jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am using a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, but found that this problem is in the underlying JdbcTemplate class, so I will show the problem as it occurs with the JdbcTemplate (so let's not worry about the safety of the SQL query here).

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY ? ?";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
            new Object[] { "name", "ASC" },
            new ClientResultSetExtractor());
```

I expected the first place-holder to be replaced with "name" and the second with "ASC", which would create the valid SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC
```

But unfortunately, running that jdbc query does not work:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2" at character 35
STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY $1 $2
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I had assumed the problem was the two placeholders in sequence, but even when I remove the first one, it still won't accept just the last one, which should tell the query whether to sort in ASC or DESC order. Is this a bug, and if not, why the heck is this not acceptable????

Comment: I've solved the problem by removing the placeholder for ASC or DESC and simply adding it to the SQL String I create dynamically... however, I'm still interested to know why the approach I was trying before didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying  to use parameters incorrectly.

Parameters are not column names or SQL statement keywords. They're data content (eg., `WHERE LastName = ?` is a valid parameterized statement, `WHERE ? = 'Smith'` is not).

Comment: Thanks... I was thinking of it more as a useful mechanism for re-writing the SQL String for me.... but clearly this is not the case.

Comment: But Spring is still allowing me to use `ORDER BY ?`, which goes against what you say.

Comment: That is really strange; I'm not sure how (or why) it would allow that functionality. I'm not any kind of expert (or even novice) with Spring, and missed that in your tags.

Comment: I believe this makes sense.... from a safety point of view, the ?'s should not be allowed to be replaced with SQL keywords, such as "ASC" and "DESC" (which is probably the root cause of my original problem), but there's no good reason why you should forbid things like replacing "ORDER BY ?" with "ORDER BY name" (other than to strictly follow the principle that ?'s are for data only, not column names or SQL keywords).

Comment: This raises the question: what if I wanted to select all clients whose names are "ASC"???? Damn! I would not be able to get correct replacement for "WHERE name = ?" if ? = "ASC". Hope that never happens... will not tell any of the testers :)

Comment: Nah... that's not the case.... SQL keywords are just changed so they are interpreted as literals by the DB (probably by placing them between quotes).